Can't ping or SSH to hosts on my network
I can't ping or SSH to hosts on my local network, including my own router, from my MBP. I'm using a wired connection in my CalDigit thunderbolt hub, and WiFi is disabled, but the problem persists regardless of which one I use (or both). Everything else works: internet, SSH'ing to hosts I run in the cloud, etc.
➜  ~ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2

Since everything else works, it seems strange to need to confirm this, but the routing table looks fine.
➜  ~ netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGScg                en11
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#17            UCS                  en11      !
192.168.1          link#17            UCS                  en11      !
192.168.1.1/32     link#17            UCS                  en11      !
192.168.1.1        68:d7:9a:6a:39:fe  UHLWIir              en11   1134
192.168.1.2        dc:a6:32:38:8b:30  UHLWIi               en11   1189
192.168.1.26       78:c8:81:81:5:a8   UHLWI                en11     44
192.168.1.31       9c:6b:0:14:6a:7a   UHLWI                en11    230
<snip>
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI               en11      !
224.0.0/4          link#17            UmCS                 en11      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI               en11
255.255.255.255/32 link#17            UCS                  en11      !

I have a couple of Linux boxes, a test server (.31), and a PiHole (.2) for local DNS. If I try to ping or SSH to either one, I get "no route to host." I'm flummoxed. It's a local LAN. There's no routing involved. The PiHole is even connected in the same switch as my wired connection to my MBP. After configuring their networks with an IP address and the right netmask, they should just arp each other and... talk. (And you can see in the routing table that my Mac is arp'ing these hosts just fine.)
Something in the Mac's IP stack is preventing either ping or SSH even getting off the machine. I've tried capturing the ping with tcpdump, but I don't see any packets. They're not even getting put "on the wire" by my Mac. It's not even trying.
On the Mac, I usually use an off-site DNS (Cloudflare or OpenDNS). However, if I add the PiHole to my list of DNS resolvers on this machine, all of a sudden I can ping AND SSH to that host, but I still can't ping the router or the other box. So macOS is making some exception when the host is a resolver, and I have no idea what that's about.
Here's the real kicker: If I DON'T have the PiHole in my list of resolvers, I can't ping it, SSH to it, or use it for DNS lookup, HOWEVER, I CAN hit the PiHole admin web app running on it! So there's some exception-to-the-exception for port 80.
Here's another kicker: If I add the router (192.168.1.1) to my list of DNS resolvers, I can ping it too. Same with the test server.
Another: Even though I can't ping or SSH to either Linux box, they can both ping the MBP just fine.
I'm not using any VPN. (Never have.)
I'm not using the Mac's firewall.
What could be causing my Mac to immediately fail pings and SSH attempts with "no route to host" on my local LAN, and not even try to put those packets on the wire (unless the host is listed as a DNS resolver, apparently)?

I'll assume that you're on Sequoia. If you're using "iTerm" or some other third-party terminal emulator, go to System Settings > Privacy & Security > Local Network and enable it.

Yes, and yes, and wow. Done in one. Please make your comment an answer so I can give you credit.

Yes, this is definitely a dupe. I had no idea it was limited to iTerm2 because I didn't think to try the native app. I mean, I get it now, but it NEVER would have occurred to me that it was the TERMINAL EMULATOR ITSELF that was getting blocked from accessing the network.
